# formulaR1C1 references wrong range when used on Excel 2003 chart

Tags: excel, charts, range, formula, vba

When I add a form CommandButton to a worksheet and insert the following(code/macro) below, it works perfectly, not a problem. When I add a CommandButton to a Chart (the exact same code-no differences), the result is a #ref error in all of the cells where I previously had a correct answer. My problem is: i want control on the chart to update the source data.

The macro is simple... (chart data in 1 column only)

```
Dim mkWb As Workbook
Dim HLDataWs As Worksheet
Dim eRw As Integer
Dim strtRnge As Range, endRnge As Range
Dim fRnge As Range

Set mkWb = Workbooks("Mktday.xls")
Set HLDataWs = mkWb.Worksheets("HLChartData")

'eRw is about 700 in my ws
eRw = HLDataWs.Cells(7, 1).End(xlDown).Row

Set strtRnge = HLDataWs.Cells(8, 14)
Set endRnge = HLDataWs.Cells(eRw, 14)
Set fRnge = HLDataWs.Range(strtRnge, endRnge)

fRnge.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C + (RC[-12]-RC[-11])"
```

from a worksheet button, this works PERFECTLY, from a chart button or other chart control, it doesn't.

If i change the syntax to .Formula it doesn't work, FormulaR1C1Local doesn't work, .Value doesn't work. If I set a correct formula in the 1st row and copy down, it works.
When I inspect the Excel formula bar after using FormulaR1C1 ,
instead of the cells showing =R[-1]C + (RC[-12]-RC[-11])
the formala bar shows: =R[65528]C[-13] + (R[-7]C[231]-R[-7]C[232])
Is there something I'm missing? I've tried using the value property,column property, and maybe 5 others. I've fiddled with Offset () with no luck. Is this a bug??

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Code works flawlessly when from a sheet, doesn't at all when from a chart.  So odd.

Anyway, thanks for looking!

Steve

Comment: change eRw = HLDataWs.Cells(7, 1).End(xlDown).Row to eRw = HLDataWs.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row and have another try - had similar effects with xlDown errors on a few sheets.

Comment: Can you use a Form control instead? That should work.

Comment: Rory. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already using a "Forms" control since Activex controls cannot be used on charts.

Comment: Therak, thanks also for your suggestion. As you suggested, I tried referencing the bottom of the range by using xlUp syntax. This causes the same ref# problem.  The code works fine when the control is on a worksheet, but fails when the control is on a chart.